# How do I use InputMismatchExeption to catch strings? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm a novice java programmer and need to adjust this code so it catches two strings instead of variables.

Here is the original code we are supposed to use:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Part4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userNum = 0;
        Scanner screen = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean inputOK = false;
        String dump = null;
        while (!inputOK) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            try {
                userNum = screen.nextInt();
                dump = screen.nextLine();
                inputOK = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                dump = screen.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\"" + dump + "\" is not a legal integer, " +
                        "please try again!");
            } // end try-catch block
        } // end input loop
        screen.close();
        userNum = userNum + 20;
        System.out.println("Your number plus 20 is " + userNum);
    }
}
```

and here is my failed attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class testClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String letter = new String();
        Scanner screen = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean inputOK = false;
        String dump = null;
        while (!inputOK) {
            System.out.print("Enter ('y' or 'n': )");
            try {
                letter = screen.nextLine();
                dump = screen.nextLine();
                inputOK = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                dump = screen.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\"" + dump + "\" is not a legal letter, " +
                    "please try again!");
            } 
        } 
        screen.close();
        System.out.println("That is a valid letter");


    }
}
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by "so it catches two strings instead of variables"?

Comment: *"How do I use InputMismatchExeption to catch strings?"* You **don't**. You check for valid values *before* trying to get them, e.g. by calling `hasNextLine()` before `nextLine()`, so you don't have to do a try-catch at all. --- And to see if user entered valid text, you compare `letter` to string literals such as `"y"` using the `equals()` method.

Comment: I'm creating a program which requires the user to enter either "y" or "n" depending on whether they would like to continue the game or not. So I need to catch anything other than the characters "y" or "n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off `InputMismatchException` will only be thrown

> to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Since anything but `y` and `n` are still `String`'s this won't be thrown. Instead you can throw a new `InputMismatchException` if it is not `y` or `n`:

```
String letter = new String();
Scanner screen = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean inputOK = false;
while (!inputOK) {
      System.out.println("Enter ('y' or 'n': )");
      try {
          letter = screen.nextLine();

          if(!letter.equals("y") && !letter.equals("n")) {
              throw new InputMismatchException();
          }


          inputOK = true;
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

          System.out.println("\"" + letter + "\" is not a legal letter, " +
                "please try again!");

      } 
  } 
  System.out.println("That is a valid letter");
```

Also it is not good practice to close `System.in`. The general rule is if you did not open a resource, you should not close it